# Joining Tables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Ambiguous Error.. It highlights this line:

```
bojDA.Fill(objDS, "ShopCart");
```

and right above that is my select statement which looks like:

any advice on this issue now would be helpful, thank you

Thank you

I think the new error has something to do with:

```
SELECT productid,productname,productsku,quantity,productprice,productprice * quantity AS TotalPrice,ShoppingCartRecID,UOM,PackingSlip,LogoDesignNumber,CustomText,NameText,ExtraCharge,custitem,t1.CatalogType,CatalogID,RelatedChargeID,UPSFlag FROM ShoppingCart t1 INNER JOIN ItemCatalogProfile t2 on t1.CatalogType = t2.Integration
```

when i try entering this into SQL Server, it just pulls back empty columns

Comment: All you have to do is have your tables joined in your select statement. Asp.Net Grids or whatever you are using will use whatever data you pass it.

Comment: should I be looking in the aspx page for a select statement, or the cs file, because the only place I find any select statements is in the C# code behind the aspx page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the tables in the select query that's used to bind the GridView (or other databound control), like this:

```
SELECT Table1.Column1,
       Table2.Column2
FROM   Table1
       INNER JOIN Table2
           ON Table1.SomeColumn = Table2.SomeColumn
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, the only confusion I have is where that is

Comment: It depends on how you access your data. Do you use stored procedures?

Comment: What are you binding the databound control to? Trace that back to the SQL query, and modify the query.

Comment: Thats what I am looking for, I have it narrowed down to a few select statements

Comment: Okay, so figure out which one is used to bind the control, and add the necessary columns and joins to the query.

Comment: Well I think i got the right one now, but it is giving me a "Ambiguous Column Name 'CatalogType' " error when the page loads I have edited the code to show where it tells me there error is, and also the select statement that is being used

Comment: Well I got the ambiguous column name fixed and I'm going to mark this as the answer, I still have work with this but it is now an entirely different subject now, Thanks for the help

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for your next question so we can iron this out.

Comment: Alright Thanks, this time im not sure what to really ask, the problem is now nothing is being saved to the shopping cart, I'm guessing im just missing an update on a statement somewhere

Comment: What do you mean? The select isn't populating the shopping cart, or you can't append new items to it?

Comment: Can you revise your question and include the code that populates the shopping cart?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to work with data from a persistant store. One is to grab raw data and attempt to shape it on the UI layer. The other is to shape the data when you retrieve it. Okay, technically, you can shape the data at any layer.

Your issue is largely due to having one data definition throughout your application. You have the same data definition in the database, the business logic and the UI. For some of the layers, separating out the data into two "sources" (or similar), where the data has different names, depending on context.

The direction I would take to solve the problem is create a "view model" that has the bits named correctly for the purpose of this particular page. You need not change the data structure throughout all layers to do this. Just shape the data for the UI before you bind it.